# Contact Form 7 Plugin emails not being received by some accounts

Tags: plugins, forms, email

I am using contact form 7 to send an email form.  I receive them, but my clients' email addresses - one at the host and one at gmail, never do. They claim that none of the messages end up in their spam folders either. The client did ask the host to take a look and they also claimed that there is no blocking of the form emails and they aren't being sent to spam.  Ideas on where things are going wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had tons of issues with the plugin Contact Form 7 in the last couple months. Especially with Wordpress 3.5.1. I started using [Formidable Pro](http://formidablepro.com/) for all of my clients in the last couple weeks. It costs a bit of money for the developer license, but the peace of mind that it is working and there is plenty support as well as additional plugins available has been priceless!

In the event that it is not Contact Form 7 that is causing the problem of sending mail check/do the following.

- Make sure the IP Address the site resides on is not Blacklisted
- Check to see if the server is set to deal with mail internally or remotely
- If all else fails, you can always configure it to send mail through an actual email account though SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that occurs on Parellels’ PLESK server administration software.

Find your ‘main.cf’ configuration file for PostFix, which for CentOS 6, is located at

```
 /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

If you can’t find it, do a

```
 which postfix
```

SSH command to at least see where Postfix is on your server.

Then, open the file up through a text editor, or in the Linux shell, and make these lines (should be at the end of the file, around line 677) :

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
```

commented out like this :

```
#virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
#virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
#virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
```

Then, restart the Postfix service

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

Apache while your at it (can’t hurt), and voila! Your email address should be receiving those emails now. This also doesn’t affect any of your regular emails or anything else, either.